# Detecting format of raw burned data which was burned as CDDA

Tags: cd-burning, cdda

Given a file containing raw data burned to a CD/DVD, I'm trying to figure out which format was used (i.e. ISO, UDF, etc.).

For example, I can detect the ISO9660 format because in the beginning of one of the 2048-byte sectors I can find the string "CD001".

However, when it comes to CDDA (Redbook) data, it seems to be much harder. I tried looking for the synchronization bytes, but wasn't very lucky so far. Another complication in this case is that each track is written to another file. In case of ISO, for example, everything is on a single track; In case of audio I got a separate file for each track.

I'm aware that this format is abused by many companies, so I'm just looking for a pretty good detection.

The specific case is to detect audio CD (in CDDA format) created by Windows Media Player.

Any suggestions?